# IonCube encoded file causes infinite loop

Tags: php, ioncube, php-8.2

I have a PHP file encoded using IonCube Encoder GUI 13.0.2.
It is a PHP 8.2.4 code that runs fine unencoded, but crashes badly when encoded - causing a message similar to this (the second number varies, and the first one is my memory_limit of 512M):

> Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 19543359488 bytes)

The file was encoded using the Encoder GUI app under Windows 10 and the error is present on the same development machine (using PHP's own webserver) and also on a production server running Debian/Apache 2.4 and PHP 8.2.14.

The encoded/unencoded file was tested under identical circumstances and input parameters (guaranteed).

The Encoder can produce ANSI or binary outputs - I've tried both of them with the same result.

I've tried with a version of the file with stripped comments/whitespaces (using `php_strip_whitespace()`). Same result.

I've tried to leave the problematic file unencoded (all others encoded) - but then the webserver dies immediately without any messages (strange behavior, this is true on both dev/production machines).

I've contacted IonCube support, but my ticket is **still unresolved**.

I can see that years ago (2014), the ionCube Loaders were fixed for infinite loop issues:
https://www.ioncube.com/sa/release-notes.php

Are there someone other users with similar problems and what could I do to solve them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's obviously a bug in ionCube then, so check for updates, check their bugtracker for similar issues and if nothing helps file a bug yourself. For that, extract a [mcve] from your code that causes ionCube to emit faulty replacement code. Perhaps this will give you a hint how to create a workaround. Also, make sure your code is sound to begin with, so make sure that PHPStan, Psalm etc don't raise any red flags. BTW: For a question here, you lack code to reproduce this. Also, if you already filed a bug ticket, at least link it to the question here and vice-versa.

Comment: It's been a while since i posted the question and (after intense conversations with their support) i can confirm it is an ionCube bug, particularly with the Windows encoder. The same stuff encoded under Linux is working as expected. According to their support, they are working to fix this.